# Django: tags showing in HTML template even after adding safe tag

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on an app. In the HTML template, the text (entered from admin) shows the paragraph tags. I have added the safe tag in my template file.

Template file:

```
            <div class="container details">
                <h5> Category: {{ single.category }} <br> </h5>                
                <h2>{{ single.title }}</h2>
                <h4> {{ single.content|safe }} </h4>
            </div>
        </section>
```

(^^ of course it's got the extends tag and block tag and all that, but this is the part with the error)

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

Example of content (input)
https://snipboard.io/nK9pTz.jpg

Example of content (output)
https://snipboard.io/ayuwN9.jpg

Please help

Comment: Show us an example of what `content` contains.

Comment: I've done it, the <p> is the problem